# Adding radio button in table row and detecting the button click in android

Tags: android, database, radio-button

I am adding a `radiobutton` in the table row which displays data from `db` dynamically. I want to edit the row on the click of `radiobutton`. How to identify on which row the `radiobutton` was clicked?

```
String selquery = "select * from student";
Cursor cursor = StudentDB.rawQuery(selquery,null) ;
if(cursor != null){
    if ((cursor != null && cursor.getCount()< 1))
    {
        cursor.close();
    }else{

        int numberOfRecords = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.datatablellayout);
        for(int i=0;i< numberOfRecords;i++){
            // Inflate your row "template" and fill out the fields.
            TableRow row = (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(SampleDbAct.this).inflate(R.layout.tablewithrow, null);
            ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.datatable_name)).setText(cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("name"))));
            ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.datatable_rno)).setText(cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("roll_number"))));
            ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.datatable_place)).setText(cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("place_name"))));
            ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.datatable_class)).setText(cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("class"))));
            ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.datatable_email)).setText(cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("e_mail"))));
            ((RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.radio_btn)).setText(cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("e_mail"))));
            table.addView(row);

            /*System.out.println("You have entered the Name as:" +cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("name")))+":");
            System.out.println("You have entered the Roll No as:" +cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("roll_number"))));
            System.out.println("You have entered the Class as:" +cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("class"))));
            System.out.println("You have entered the place as:" +cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("place_name"))));
            System.out.println("You have entered the email as:" +cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("e_mail"))));*/

            if(!cursor.isLast())
                cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        table.requestLayout();
        cursor.close();
    }
}

StudentDB.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You detect a tap of a radio button by setting its onClickListener with button.setOnClickListener.  When the listener is called, it will pass in the view that was touched.  If the view alone isn't enough, you can use the view's tag to pass along some information to determine the row's data (generally an array index or the object the row was generated from) with setTag() and getTag().

Comment: Could you please give me the code... sorry I am not able to figure out as I am a beginner in android

Comment: Thank you Gabe Sechan .. I would be happy if I could get some code on how to do this..